# How to delete all temp files and settings after uninstalling a software?

Tags: uninstall, cache, spyder

There is some error in spyder, hence I want to uninstall it and re-install with all the new settings. But when I reinstalled it, the settings were as previous. Also, it is not possible to manually find all the folders and files associated with it and then delete them. So how do I uninstall spyder with all its settings, temporary files, cache etc., so that when I reinstall it, it is absolutely new?

Comment: How did you install it? If using `apt`/Ubuntu software center you can `sudo apt purge {package}`  and it will also remove configs. But you can also do it manual: the cache will be in /home/$USER/ in a hidden directory.  1 thing: I did not see any "caching"  for spyder. 2nd thing: Would it not be the better for you to ask about a fix for the error?

Comment: I installed it using Ubuntu software. `sudo apt purge {package}` does not work. How to find that "hidden" directory in /home/$USER/ .

Answer (score 1):

As you've already tried `apt purge`, you could try to find any files related to Spyder and delete them yourself. For example, it sounds like the configuration is (or was at one point) located in `~/.spyder2`, so you could delete that directory, if it exists.

Other places that applications commonly store data are `~/.config`, `~/.local/share` and `~/.cache`.

If you want to find all files on your system with `spyder` in the name, you can run this command:

```
find / -iname '*spyder*' 2>/dev/null
```

(it may take a while if you have slow storage).

There's not any generic way to automatically delete all the files created by a typical Linux application, because that data is not tracked.

Comment: Will this delete hidden files as well?

Comment: Minor quibble: All the files created by dpkg and apt during an installation *are* tracked, and you can see them using `dpkg -L <packagename>`. dpkg simply won't remove files in /home under any circumstances (to protect your data) - the user must clean out /home themself.

Comment: After finding and deleting all those files, Ubuntu software center shows "No application found" on searching for spyder.

Comment: @user535733 For sure, the files created as part of the install are tracked, but files created at any point after that (e.g. configuration, caches) aren't.

Comment: @Josh agreed, and that's not what your answer says.

Comment: @user535733 Feel free to edit it if you think you can improve it.